# Can element attributes be accessed using a dot notation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on a script that dynamically creates a group of buttons, all of which are created with a class attribute so that I can style them. But the styling never worked.

I added the class value like so: `button.class = "foo";` where `button` is a reference to the `<button>` element in the DOM.

I changed the above code to `button.setAttribute("class", "foo");` and it works!

But this has me confused because I use the dot notation (or object property notation? I don't know what to call it) to set other values, like the attribute `value`.

For example, I have an event listener on some buttons. When they're clicked, the `value` attribute is added to the element. When it's clicked again, it's removed:

```
button.onclick = function() {
  if (this.value)
    this.removeAttribute("value");
  else
    this.value = "bar";
}
```

The above works as expected.

So my question is - why is it that notations like `button.class = "foo";` seem to work with some attributes and not with others? And is there a way to find which attributes will behave appropriately using that notation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property to get and set the value of the `class` attribute of the specified element.

> The name `className`is used for this property instead of `class` because of conflicts with the "class" keyword in many languages which are used to manipulate the DOM.

```
button.className= "foo"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! Where could I find a reference to all the other attributes that can be accessed in that way?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the webpage doesn't say anything about a 'value' property. How does something like "button.value = 'bar';" work? which API does the "value" property belong to?

Comment: @Manuel, Yes that will work. Documentation are avalauble you need to check at correct location for [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) and [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)